# How to prevent material-ui popover from scrolling an iFrame on open?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

I'm working on an application using MaterialUI that embeds in other pages using an iFrame. Whenever we show a component that renders into a `Popover` (both MUI `select` and `menu` components do this), the iFrame scrolls / jumps position as the popover opens.

Here is an example where this happens.
https://erehd6.csb.app

Happens in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

To reproduce, you will need to scroll the iFrame off the top of the page. Then the popover demo buttons will exhibit this behavior, or the overflow menus to access code sources off the site (github/stackblitz/copy JS source/copy TS source):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
        <iframe src="https://v4.mui.com/api/popover/" style="border: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></iframe>
        <div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I prevent this scrolling/jump from happening? The `Popper` component does not have this same issue, but I can't figure out how to replace the Popover with the Popper in a way that doesn't require a library fork (and a huge amount of re-testing our application). This happens in all versions of MUI btw, but I couldn't put the current site into an iFrame.

I tried replacing the transition component of `Grow` with `Fade` but that did not help. I'm still trying to pinpoint the exact issue, it's somewhere in the [positioning code for the Popover.](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Popover/Popover.js#L281)

Comment: quick recommendation: provide a pastebin link (e.g. codesandbox) to quickly peruse your implementation and get faster feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `disableAutoFocus={true}` property to any `Popover` or any other component relying on Popover should prevent any scrolling weirdness. You might need to use `disableEnforceFocus` as well, depending on what behavior you desire. These are props from the `Modal` component (of which `Popover` is a "child" of): https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/

I just ran into a similar problem when using a `<Menu />` in an iframe, which when opened, caused the browser to scroll the page and focus on the iframe. In the case of this `<Menu />`, I also had to add a `autoFocusItem: false` property to the `MenuListProps`, so these are the relevant props for me:

```
<Menu
  MenuListProps={{
    autoFocusItem: false,
  }}
  disableAutoFocus
  /* other props */
>
  {/* MenuList components */}
</Menu>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Do you have any tips about how you managed the focus state / accessibility after that?

Comment: Sorry, we have not had to worry about focus state/accessibility in relation to this specific component/usecase. I assume that handling the focus programmatically will cause this browser jump due to how Chrome handles focus. Have you had any progress on this since making your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @amitt said. In order to allow for both accessibility and to fix the menu jumping you can in addition to disableAutoFocus and autoFocusItem: false, you can manage your own focus state.

By using a ref, you can control the focus on enter.

```
const onFocus = () => {
    ref?.current?.children[2].children[0].firstChild.focus();
};

<Menu
  MenuListProps={{
     autoFocusItem: false,
  }}
  disableAutoFocus
  ref={ref}
  TransitionProps={{
     onEntered: onFocus,
  }} 
  /* other props */
>
  {/* MenuList components */}
</Menu>
```

Comment: I wish I could mark both as the answer! Especially because this portion if so important to accessibility.